# Does Azure.Devices.Client Retry Policy work on Timeout Exception?

Tags: azure, amqp, azure-iot-hub

I am using Microsoft.Azure.Devices nuget package to send packets onto the IOT Hub device over AMQP. I have also applied an exponential retry policy as well. My service was working perfectly fine however yesterday I received System.Timeout Exception on SendEventAsync method. I create a client at the start of the service and use the same client to send messages to IOT hub. I think that the retry policy did not work as it did not refresh the connection automatically. I had to restart the service and only then connection reestablished. Do I need to catch the timeout exception and refresh the client manually or does the retry mechanism handles it?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? Did you change anything on the SendEventAsync method and started seeing this error? Is this a transient failure or recurring?

Comment: I did not change anything on the SendEventAsync method. I just got this exception once and haven't received a similar error again.